# Can someone help explain to me this Windows 11 minidump error information (via WinDbg)?

Tags: windows-11, crash, minidumps

My W11 machine has started crashing recently. So yes, something "recently installed" has caused it. I'm not sure what though.

I have a mini dump of the most recent crash. Trying to use WinDbg to give me some clues (e.g. is it an updated driver? etc..)

EDIT: [here's the dump file](https://file.io/zak6FndPLli0) (2.6MB)

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25200.1003 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\121022-19562-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 22621 MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff807`4b000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff807`4bc13410
Debug session time: Sat Dec 10 15:03:38.102 2022 (UTC + 10:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 22:06:43.278
Loading Kernel Symbols
..

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

...............................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.............................................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff807`4b4283c0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:fffffc01`74a0d510=000000000000003b
4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the BugCheck
Arg2: fffff807527f20c8, Address of the instruction which caused the BugCheck
Arg3: fffffc0174a0de60, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the BugCheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1953

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 29759

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 4

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 43

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 265

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 39439

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 112

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.DumpHeader
    Value: 0x3b

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.Register
    Value: 0x3b

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
    Value: 1808

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.DiagDataWrittenToHeader
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.ErrorCode
    Value: 0

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.KernelGeneratedTriageDump
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.LastLine
    Value: Dump completed successfully.

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.ProgressPercentage
    Value: 0


FILE_IN_CAB:  121022-19562-01.dmp

TAG_NOT_DEFINED_202b:  *** Unknown TAG in analysis list 202b


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1808
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

BUGCHECK_CODE:  3b

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff807527f20c8

BUGCHECK_P3: fffffc0174a0de60

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

CONTEXT:  fffffc0174a0de60 -- (.cxr 0xfffffc0174a0de60)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=ffffab0d6f74af60 rcx=ffffab0d6f74ad00
rdx=0000000000000520 rsi=ffffab0d6f74af70 rdi=ffffab0d6f74ad00
rip=fffff807527f20c8 rsp=fffffc0174a0e880 rbp=fffffc0174a0e9f0
 r8=0000000000000400  r9=7ffffffffffffffc r10=fffff8074b2c93b0
r11=fffffc0174a0e8e8 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000040002
r14=ffffab0d6f74ad00 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00050246
dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESSVM::DestroyVmProcess+0x8c:
fffff807`527f20c8 488ba860020000  mov     rbp,qword ptr [rax+260h] ds:002b:00000000`00000260=????????????????
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  vmwp.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
fffffc01`74a0e880 fffff807`527098f6     : 00000000`00000110 fffffc01`74a0e9f0 ffff9a84`371ff210 ffff9a84`41ff0080 : dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESSVM::DestroyVmProcess+0x8c
fffffc01`74a0e8f0 fffff807`5265f904     : ffffab0d`6f74ad00 fffff807`4b000000 00000000`00040002 ffffab0d`6c9b4660 : dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESS::Destroy+0xac566
fffffc01`74a0ea90 fffff807`52709650     : ffffab0d`6cc926a8 ffffab0d`6f74ad00 ffffab0d`6cc92668 00000000`00000002 : dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESS::DestroyDxgProcess+0x13c
fffffc01`74a0ec20 fffff807`5281730e     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`377c97e0 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESS::Destroy+0xac2c0
fffffc01`74a0edc0 fffff807`52818acc     : ffff9a84`2ed484d0 ffff9a84`377b3000 ffff0b7b`17a66d75 00000000`00000000 : dxgkrnl!ADAPTER_RENDER::ResetVirtualFunction+0x206
fffffc01`74a0ef10 fffff807`525275ff     : ffff9a84`416d2aa0 00000000`00224000 ffff9a84`00000000 ffff9a84`41f64bc8 : dxgkrnl!DxgkDdiResetVirtualFunction+0x5c
fffffc01`74a0ef70 fffff807`80911389     : 00000000`0000000c fffff807`808ee530 ffff9a84`2e9d9030 ffff9a84`41ab4df0 : dxgkrnl!DpiDdiResetVirtualFunction+0x2f
fffffc01`74a0efa0 fffff807`809027b9     : ffff9a84`41ab4df0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00224084 : vpcivsp!SriovProxy::ResetVf+0x49
fffffc01`74a0efe0 fffff807`8090432a     : ffff9a84`416d2aa0 fffff807`4fdc2fed 0000657b`be09b498 0000657b`d12b7c01 : vpcivsp!VirtualDeviceResetFunction+0xf5
fffffc01`74a0f050 fffff807`808fe037     : ffff9a84`416d2aa0 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`3e9bd4f0 ffff9a84`41ab4d20 : vpcivsp!VirtualDeviceRemove+0x96
fffffc01`74a0f080 fffff807`808fb73d     : 0000657b`d12b7ce8 fffffc01`74a0f130 00000000`00224084 ffff9a84`41ab4d20 : vpcivsp!VpciIoctlRemoveDevice+0xab
fffffc01`74a0f0b0 fffff807`4fdc525b     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffff9a84`3e9bd4f0 fffffc01`74a0f240 : vpcivsp!VspEvtIoDeviceControl+0x2bd
fffffc01`74a0f170 fffff807`4fdc4f06     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`2ed1ecd0 ffff9a84`2ed13880 : Wdf01000!FxIoQueue::DispatchRequestToDriver+0x16b [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxioqueue.cpp @ 3325] 
fffffc01`74a0f1e0 fffff807`4fdc4c32     : ffff9a84`2ed13880 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Wdf01000!FxIoQueue::DispatchEvents+0x216 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxioqueue.cpp @ 3125] 
fffffc01`74a0f260 fffff807`4fdc63ac     : ffff9a84`3e9bd400 ffff9a84`2ed13880 80000000`00000001 ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 : Wdf01000!FxIoQueue::QueueRequestFromForward+0x172 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxioqueue.cpp @ 2496] 
fffffc01`74a0f2e0 fffff807`4fdc5e51     : ffff9a84`11ef0000 ffff9a84`2ed1ecd0 fffffc01`74a0f3d9 00000000`00000001 : Wdf01000!FxPkgIo::EnqueueRequest+0xb8 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxpkgio.cpp @ 699] 
fffffc01`74a0f350 fffff807`808fb427     : ffff9a84`2ed48310 0000657b`c1642b08 ffff9a84`2ecd7b38 ffff9a84`3e9bd4f0 : Wdf01000!imp_WdfDeviceEnqueueRequest+0x81 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\core\fxdeviceapi.cpp @ 2104] 
fffffc01`74a0f380 fffff807`4fdc6654     : ffff9a84`3e9bd4f0 fffffc01`74a0f580 ffff9a84`3e9bd4f0 ffff9a84`2ecd79b0 : vpcivsp!VspEvtIoInCallerContext+0x167
fffffc01`74a0f440 fffff807`4fdc4910     : ffff9a84`3e9bd4f0 ffff9a84`2ed13880 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Wdf01000!FxPkgIo::DispatchToInCallerContextCallback+0x90 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxpkgio.cpp @ 1757] 
fffffc01`74a0f480 fffff807`4fdc42ce     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 00000000`00000001 ffff9a84`2ed1ecd0 : Wdf01000!FxPkgIo::DispatchStep1+0x630 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxpkgio.cpp @ 324] 
fffffc01`74a0f550 fffff807`4fdc7b41     : ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 ffff9a84`00000000 00000000`000000c9 00000000`00000000 : Wdf01000!FxPkgIo::Dispatch+0x5e [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\irphandlers\io\fxpkgio.cpp @ 119] 
fffffc01`74a0f5b0 fffff807`4b2cb875     : ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 fffffc01`74a0f6a1 00000000`00000002 : Wdf01000!FxDevice::DispatchWithLock+0x81 [minkernel\wdf\framework\shared\core\fxdevice.cpp @ 1446] 
fffffc01`74a0f600 fffff807`4b6c2c70     : ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 00000000`00000002 ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 ffff9a84`40fdeee0 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x55
fffffc01`74a0f640 fffff807`4b6c123c     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00224084 fffffc01`74a0fa60 ffff9a84`4de8fdc0 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1d0
fffffc01`74a0f6f0 fffff807`4b6bf516     : 00000000`00000000 fffffc01`74a0fa60 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x72c
fffffc01`74a0f900 fffff807`4b43d1e5     : ffff9a84`41ff0080 0000009f`1047f138 fffffc01`74a0f988 00000000`00224084 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
fffffc01`74a0f970 00007ff8`6462eee4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
0000009f`1047f118 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff8`6462eee4


SYMBOL_NAME:  dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESSVM::DestroyVmProcess+8c

MODULE_NAME: dxgkrnl

IMAGE_NAME:  dxgkrnl.sys

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.22621.815

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffffc0174a0de60 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  8c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_dxgkrnl!DXGPROCESSVM::DestroyVmProcess

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {f8b784e7-4a0a-0c3e-6b99-2f965f88fe26}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

the 2x clues I'm guessing are:

- vmwp.exe (is this Hyper-V because I have docker installed on this laptop?)
- dxgkrnl.sys (something with DirectX ???)

My son said he was playing a game .. so that might be the DirectX bit?

Is it worth changing the crash details from a minidump to a "Kernal" or "Complete" dump to get more info?

In the past, I usually just do a format c:/ when this crap happens. But for once, I'd love to actually learn and see if I can determine the cause .. and even see if I can try and fix it .. versus a full blown format. (side note: A format will probably be quicker but it's really important for me to learn, etc).

Can anyone help, please?

Please don't think I'm asking someone "to fix my computer" as that is  not the case. I want to fix it myself. I would love some help learning how *I can see the causes* for these crash-reboots (there's not even a BSOD anymore).

If I learn which software might be causing grief with my setup, I could at least attempt to reinstall or try different versions of things, etc.

--
Important extra info: this was original post over at SO but closed. It was suggested I ask over here (site == more specific to the question).

I'm also not sure if even this is the correct StackExchange site to ask this on ..

Comment: See if this article helps:   https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-ntoskrnl-exe-bsod/

Comment: You might also find Nirsoft Blue Screen view to be easier to use. It is not as powerful as Microsoft WinDbg but still very good. I use it myself.

Comment: I am guessing that this has to do with either graphics drivers or intel chipset drivers.  I am also guessing that the VM stuff is just a result of something crashing further down in the stack having nothing to do with VM stuff directly.  I suggest you run Run [DriverView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html) - set VIEW to Hide Microsoft drivers - update those without "Dump" in their names (and update BIOS and chipset).  Also, windows uses backslashes and not forward slashes.

Comment: Oh, one more thing.  I am +1ing you for a beautifully written question with ALL HOMEWORK completed.   It might also help if you attach the actual dump so we can look it it in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the positive and helpful suggestions. I'll try and action them, right now.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas >  attach the actual dump . Oh, great idea! here it is: https://file.io/zak6FndPLli0  (i hope this website is ok .. otherwise i'll move it to another, if suggested).  If that dump -does help- .. can you please explain the steps what you did to discover what is going on, please?

Comment: I am an engineer that learned (as a kid) how to write assembler in 1982.  I have written everything from device drivers to user mode applications.  How do I know?  I look closely at the call stack and see if I can spot something that helps me deduce a clue for the crash (nothing special).  I am simply adept a examining the call stack (as many here are).  Your dump is no longer avail.

Comment: Oh damn - that dump (which i uploaded) is also from _end of last year_ !!! Hmm. i need to learn/find out where last weeks (and today's mini dump (i tried some things like newer nvidia driver, today ... but still crashed) ) is stored. I thought it was c:\windows\minidump but there is a single one .. and it's old.